# ionic2: how to upgrade to new ionic version in the same project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using `ionic` version `3.9.2`, I installed

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader --save
```

and followed the instruction here:
[ngx-translate](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/)

But i got this error:

```
Cannot find the '@angular/common/http'
```

and after search I found that this problem is because of my `Ionic` version.

**So I want to upgrade my Ionic version in my project, what should i do?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your ionic version. The problem is that the current version of `http-loader` uses `HttpClient` which is only supported in Angular versions greater than `4.3`. The current version of ionic is on Angular version `4.1.3`.

How to fix it? Install the last version of `http-loader` with the old `Http` client like this:

```
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader@0.1.0 --save
```

[Here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/629) is the github issue for that topic.